# Running Selenium tests with Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have a Maven web project in which I must run some Selenium UI tests (with JUnit). However, when I build the project (goals: “clean install”) the Selenium tests don’t work because the Tomcat server hasn’t started yet.

I have added a plugin snippet that I found online (the tomcat7-maven-plugin) but it doesn’t seem to do anything.

It might be important to know that my Selenium tests use a Firefox driver with a different binary from my default Firefox install (an older version of Firefox portable to work with the older version of Selenium).

**This is my POM.XML file:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.web3</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebShopWeb3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat-run</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-war-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shutdown</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>WebShopWeb3</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1211.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My project (the tests are highlighted):

[image]

Does anybody know the lines I need to add to my POM.XML or other things I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple app with selenium. Here is the pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>foo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Foo App</name>
<description>Test Scenario For Foo</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: this seems irrelative to the question. the problem faced by OP seems to be around the tomcat startup and not these dependencies.

Comment: Indeed. As you can see, I have the necessary dependencies. When you build the maven project, do your Selenium tests run on a Tomcat server? What build configuration (Maven goals etc) do you use?